# Generating concatenated dataframe output from for loop over a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function:

```
def func(x):
    y = pd.read_csv(x)
    return y
```

In case i have to loop this function for severeal inputs i am expected to have combined dataframe from all those inputs as output:

```
list = ["a.csv", "b.csv", "d.csv", "e.csv"]

for i in list:
    m = func(x)
```

How can i get value of `m` as combined dataframes from all the input files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For combine DataFrames use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) in list comprehension:

Notice: Dont use `list` like variable, because python code word.

```
L = ["a.csv", "b.csv", "d.csv", "e.csv"]
df1 = pd.concat([func(x) for i in L])
```

Or in loop:

```
out = []
for i in L:
    m = func(x)
    out.append(m)

df1 = pd.concat(out)
```